# DataTableEditor plugin null string parameter at controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

Morning, I have been working through this problem for a while now and cannot figure what set up I have wrong with this code. The intention is to have a grid (DataTable) and allow in line editing for that data (Editor). I have the datatable getting the data from one ajax call and the editor is using another to update the record. The initial ajax is fine and populates properly but when I initiate an update the parameter I am sending is null. Here is some code:

```
    <div>
      <table id="post-table" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
           <tr role="row">
               <th>postID</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
     </table>
   </div>

    <script src="~/Content/DataTables-1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/editor-1.9.0/js/dataTables.editor.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/DataTables-1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var editor;

        editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor(
        {
           ajax: {
              edit: {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "/ActivationCampaign/UpdatePostRecord",
                 dataType: "json",
                 contentType: "application/json",
                                    data: function (data) {

                                        var obj = data.data;
                                        var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];

                                        var theJson = {};
                                        theJson["campaignVersionID"] = @ViewBag.CampaignID;
                                        theJson["salesChannelID"] = @ViewBag.SalesChannel;
                                        theJson["postID"] = key;
                                        theJson['amount'] = obj[key].amount;

                                        return JSON.stringify(theJson);
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            table: "#post-table",
                            idSrc: "postID",
                            fields: [{
                                label: "",
                                name: "amount"
                            }]
                        }),

                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $('#post-table').DataTable({
                                "ajax": {
                                    "url": "/ActivationCampaign/LowLevelBudgetsForChannel?campaignID=@ViewBag.CampaignID&SalesChannelID=@ViewBag.SalesChannel",
                                    "type": "GET",
                                    "datatype": "json",
                                    "dataSrc": ''
                                },
                                "pagingType": "simple",
                                "columnDefs": [
                                    {"targets": [0], "visible": false, "searchable": false, "title": "post-id"},
                                    {"targets": [1], "title": "Post" },
                                    {"targets": [2], "title": "Post Number"},
                                    {"targets": [3], "title": "Allocated Amount", "className": "allocated-column editable"},
                                    {"targets": [4], "title": "Consumed Amount"}
                                ],
                                "columns": [
                                    { "data": "postID" },
                                    { "data": "postName"},
                                    { "data": "postNumber" },
                                    { "data": "amount" },
                                    { "data": "formatedAmount" },
                                ],
                                "initComplete": function (settings, json)
                                {
                                    populateConsumed();
                                }
                            });
                        },

                        $('#post-table').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e)
                        {
                            editor.inline(this);
                        }));//end of doc ready

                        function populateConsumed()
                        {
                            var totalAmount = 0;

                            $(".allocated-column").each(function () {

                                var values = $(this).text().replace(',', '');
                                if (values > 0)
                                {
                                    totalAmount += parseFloat(values);
                                }
                            });

                            $('#txtchangeBudget').val(JSON.stringify(totalAmount).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
                        }
                    </script>




                    </div>
```

And the actions:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public JsonResult LowLevelBudgetsForChannel(int campaignID, int salesChannelID)
    {//TODO get defensive on the parameters
        return Json(activationCampaignService.GetLowLevelBudgetsForChannel(
            campaignID, salesChannelID),
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        );
    }        

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdatePostRecord([FromBody]string budgetRecord)
    {
        if(budgetRecord == null)
        {

        }

        return Json("hello");
        //return Json(activationCampaignService.UpdatePostRecord(budgetRecord));
    }
```

The `LowLevelBudgetsForChannel` call works fine but the `UpdatePostRecord` always has a null value in `budgetRecord`. Notice the HttpPost attribute comes from a different package than the other one but I have only just changed that but I am concerned that I now have both `System.Net.Http` and `System.Web.Http` installed, does anyone know of any problems that will cause.

As I need to construct the json to send and the data getting sent represents data in more than one table I would prefer to send the string and process it in the action. Cuurently IE debugger shows that it thinks I am sending this:

```
{"campaignVersionID":186,"salesChannelID":45,"postID":"20","amount":"1001"}
```

I have landed on a legacy system here and there is a lot wrong but I don't believe this has anything to do with that and I just haven't set this up correctly. I did originally not have the content type or data types set correctly or the from body attribute but following that advice has not solved my issue. Any advice on it?

[edit]
Iam currently thinking that it is related to the serialisation that happens as I have had Fiddler on it and the values are sent in the request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed in the end was to create type that matched the structure of the javascript I was sending and it all got populated correctly. So probably was some kind of serialisation error under the hood somewhere. Does anyone have a reason why a string would fail to be bound like that?